# Android studio дублирует библиотеки(экспорт проекта unity в androidStudio)

Tags: android, unity3d, firebase, gradle

Установил в проекте Unity firebase. Зарезолвил зависимости резолвером.
В проекте юнити остались только нужные либы, среди них, к примеру, либа

com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.0.2

Экспорчу проект, стартую билд и получаю DuplicateClassException

```
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.tasks.SuccessContinuation found in modules com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.0.2-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.0.2:) and play-services-tasks-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task found in modules com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.0.2-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.0.2:) and play-services-tasks-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource found in modules com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.0.2-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.0.2:) and play-services-tasks-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskExecutors found in modules com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.0.2-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.0.2:) and play-services-tasks-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks found in modules com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.0.2-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.0.2:) and play-services-tasks-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.tasks.zza found in modules com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.0.2-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.0.2:) and play-services-tasks-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzb found in modules com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.0.2-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.0.2:) and play-services-tasks-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0)
```

Откуда то он находит старую версию этой либы(17.0.0) и успешно с ней конфликтует.

И это происходит с абсолютно каждой либой! В юнити после резолва у меня 57 файлов библиотек aar, а андроид студия подтягивает еще столько же, но более старой версией. Зачем она это делает и как это отключить?

По всем файлам build.gradle в проекте посмотрел, нигде tasks 17 версии не указано. Единственно что внушает подозрение, это вот эта строчка

```
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

Может она подтягивает все то же самое что исходно есть в проекте но версии пониже?

Как узнать, в этом ли дело(отловить кто подтягивает зависимость tasks 17.0.0) и если дело в этом - как подружить между собой библиотеки которые экспортированы в проект и которые проект подтягиваем сам? Есть ли какой то инструмент - resolver, как для юнити google services resolver?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html